# How to show by default only a subset of the traces by default with plotly.graph_objs.Bar

Tags: python, plotly

When building Bar Charts with multiple traces using Plotly `graph_objs`, it shows by default all traces.

Is there a way to show only one by default and then give the use the option to show more than one?

Using the example below, by default the chart will display the bars both for `year_count` and `year_amount`, is there a way to show by default only `year_amount` and give the user the option to show both?

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df = pd.DataFrame({"year": [2019] * 3 + [2020] * 8, 
                   "amount": [3, 10, 5, 2, 20, 8, 3, 2, 4, 5, 10]})
df_grp = df.groupby("year").agg(
    year_count=("amount", "count"),
    year_amt_sum=("amount", "sum")
).reset_index()

fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(x=df_grp["year"], y=df_grp["year_count"], name="year_count"),
               go.Bar(x=df_grp["year"], y=df_grp["year_amt_sum"], name="year_amount")])
fig.show()
```

Example above was run with Python 3.7.3, pandas 1.0.2 and Plotly 4.3.0.

Comment: Please conisider sharing a reproducible snippet with a data sample. As your code now stands, it returns `TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'` at `year_amt_sum=("amount", "sum")`

Comment: @vestland I was able to run the code above. I added the Python and packages versions I used, because I suspect that with pandas < 0.25 the named aggregations might not work.